# how to check if it's Saturday and set to nearest Day in the same month

Tags: java, calendar

How to check if the date falls on a Saturday, then it will be set to nearest day in the same month?

**2 Scenarios:**

1. E.g. If Saturday falls on 21st, then it will be set to 20th,
   Friday
2. E.g. If Saturday falls on 1st, then it will be set to
   3rd (Monday)

Comment: You probably want to look up `java.util.Calendar` - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: I'd suggest to avoid Calendar like the plague if you are using Java 8 and instead look at the new javax.time APIs

Comment: how does the 2nd scenario satisfy "then it will be set to nearest day in the same month"?

Comment: Thanks for the highlight. Have change the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if I have understood exactly what you want, but do you want something like this (Java 8 needed...)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(toNearestDayInSameMonthIfSaturday(LocalDate.of(2015, 4, 4))); // Print 2015-04-05
    System.out.println(toNearestDayInSameMonthIfSaturday(LocalDate.of(2015, 4, 18))); // Print 2015-04-19
    System.out.println(toNearestDayInSameMonthIfSaturday(LocalDate.of(2015, 4, 25))); // Print 2015-04-25
}

private static LocalDate toNearestDayInSameMonthIfSaturday(LocalDate local) {
    LocalDate result;
    if (local.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY) {
        LocalDate plusOneDay = local.plusDays(1);
        LocalDate minusOneDay = local.minusDays(1);

        if (plusOneDay.getMonthValue() != local.getMonthValue()) {
            result = minusOneDay;
        } else {
            result = plusOneDay;
        }
    } else {
        result = local;
    }

    return result;
}
```